# How to get the match in Regex.Replace()?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to have a method for catching the years from the string and put theme between `(` and `)` and I'm very noob in regex. For example

```
This is 2014 and the next year will be 2015
```

is going to be

```
This is (2014) and the next year will be (2015)
```

I'm using `\d{4}` for capturing the year but I have no idea if there's possible to send the string to the next parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below regex would capture exactly the four digits from the input string. In the replacement part, parenthesis are added before and after to the captured digits.

Regex:

```
(\b\d{4}\b)
```

Replacement string:

```
($1)
```

Code:

```
string str = "This is 2014 and the next year will be 2015";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\b\d{4}\b)", "($1)");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9DOJ3Y)

**Pattern Explantion:**

- `()` - [Capturing groups.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- `\b` - It's called word boundary. It matches between a word character `\w` and a non-word character `\W`.
- `\d{4}`- Matches exactly four digits.
- `\b` - Matches between a word character and a non-word charcter.

Comment: Another [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k3ckny), you're so fast man..

Comment: @YuliamChandra it's better to use word boundary.

Comment: Thanks :) that worked :) [this](http://ideone.com/fnA7LJ) is the real test

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you'd do this:

```
Input: "This is 2014 and the next year will be 2015"
Pattern: "\d{4}"
Replacement: "($0)"
```

But this will match all numeric values that are 4 digits long, as per your pattern.

**NOTE**

The `$0` or `$&` are used in the string replacement patterns to refer to the whole match rather than to any captured substrings.

Comment: I used `$1` instead of `$0` and that worked. What's the differences?

Comment: because of capturing group. You need to refer the group index 1 inorder to get the values from 1st group.

Comment: Maybe think of it as the index of the captured match (indicated by parentheses in a regex pattern). You can check out this resource - I always use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I updated the answer to show one does not have to use any capturing groups to refer to the match value from the string replacement pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
string pattern = @"\(\d{4}\)";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, pattern , "($1)");
```

This will find any 4 digits number enclosed in open/close brackets.
If the year number can change, I think that Regex is the best approach .

Instead this code will tell you if there a match for your pattern

Comment: You didn't understand the question. I'm using the regex but I didn't know how to retrieve the matched string.

Comment: sorry for that, i have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"This is 2014 and the next year will be 2015".replace(/(\d{4})/gi, '($1)');
```

Comment: Not with C# you won't!

Comment: does `System.String.Replace()` use regex?